# Take table cell value into PHP post

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, cell

I'm having a problem adjusting the values being passed into `$_POST` from the table I have set up.

Here's the code that's being used to set up the table:

```
print "<form action=\"updateitem.php\" method=\"post\">\n";
print "<table border cellpadding = 3>\n";
print "<tr>\n";
print "<th>Menu item id</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu item name</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu item price</th>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $mi = explode("_",$info['meta_key']);
    if ($mi[2] == "food")
        $mi[2] = "takeout";
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<td id=\"meta_id\">".$info['meta_id']."<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"meta_id".$i."\" value=\"".$info['meta_id']."\" /></td>\n";
    print "<td>".$info['post_title']."</td>\n";
    print "<td>".$mi[2]."</td>\n";
    print "<td id=\"price\" contenteditable=\"true\">".$info['meta_value']."<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"meta_value".$i."\" value=\"".$info['meta_value']."\" /></td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
print "</table>\n";     
print "<input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n";
print "</form>\n";
```

What I'm trying to do is that when someone changes the price cell, I want the updated price to be passed in the `$_POST` for PHP. Is that possible?

Comment: When that form is submitted the form field 'price' WILL be submitted to updateitem.php. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contenteditable` attribute is not going to help you here.
You have to use javascript to notice when that is changed and do something with it.

The simple answer is, you need to make the `<input>` field available to the user. So change the `type="hidden"` to `type="text"` or add another field that is not hidden for the user to interact with, and then the value will be passed back to your script in `$_POST`.

Suggested changes

```
print "<form action=\"updateitem.php\" method=\"post\">\n";
print "<table border cellpadding = 3>\n";
print "<tr>\n";
print "<th>Menu item id</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu item name</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu</th>\n";
print "<th>Menu item price</th>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $mi = explode("_",$info['meta_key']);
    if ($mi[2] == "food")
        $mi[2] = "takeout";
    print "<tr>\n";
    print '<td id="meta_id">' . $info['meta_id'] . '<input type="hidden" name="meta_id[]" value="' . $info['meta_id'] . '" /></td>';
    print '<td>'.$info['post_title'].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$mi[2].'</td>';
    print '<td id="price">';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="original_price[]" value="' . $info['meta_value'] . '" />';
        print '<input type="text" name="price[]" value="' . $info['meta_value'] . '" />';
    print '</td>';
    print "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
print "</table>\n";     
print "<input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n";
print "</form>\n";
```

I took the liberty of changing the names ( `name="name[]"` ) to use arrays instead of ( `name="name" . $i` )

This will return the fields as arrays in the $_POST array
So `$_POST[price] will itself be an array` like so:

```
$_POST['price][0]
$_POST['price][1]   // and so on
```

So you can process the changed prices as

```
foreach ( $_POST['price'] as $i => $price ) {
    if ( $price != $_POST['original_price'][$i]) {
        // We have a price change lets update the database
        // using $_POST['meta_id'][$i] as the key to the database table ? I assume ??
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey RiggsFolly, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that seems to only give one result and not the entire table. Thanks.

Comment: Actually sorry I take that back. Using the foreach loop brings out every item. Thanks for your help RiggsFolly!